# Best way to update RSS feeds

Tags: php, caching, rss

My website have thousands of feeds. Some of them are being downloaded all the time, some of them only few times a month and some of them never.

Example:

- most_popular_products.rss (10 downloads/minute)
- category1.rss (10 downloads/day)
- product1_comments.rss (0 downloads/day)

Keeping in mind these disproportions, what are the best solutions to handle updating feeds?

My ideas:

- Cron script which run every hour for every feed - check for updates and if there are any replace existing static rss file with the newly created one (thousands of cron scripts, most of them will update unused feeds)
- Make name_of_feed.rss a PHP file which will decide what to do - return a cached version of feed or create a new one (every download means another run of a PHP script - requires many server resources)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personaly go with the cron.

10 requests per minute is not a lot and your web server can easily serve that, it is like 1 request per 6 second average.

Or maybe a better solution, based on how often you insert new content in your website, you can update your feed every time you add some new article to website.

So more suitable question is how often do you update content that you need to have in your rss feed.

If it is not that often I would go for that, update rss feed every time you add some new content.

Comment: New products are being added all the time - about 500/day. Every new product mean several feeds updates - new_products, productID_comment, categoryX, categoryY, shopID.

Comment: In that case my vote goes for cron job option, 2 per hour would be ok.